# How to implement reactive Java programming with DB2 database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive

We have a spring boot application which talks to DB2 using Spring JPA Repository, what is the alternative for Spring JPA Repository in reactive world which can talk to DB2

Comment: We have to rewrite the existing Spring Boot application which uses DB2 as database using Spring JPA in reactive style. now is there any other alternative for Spring JPA in reactive world as such??

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
Now Hibernate support reactive https://hibernate.org/reactive/

### UPDATE:
IBM DB2 has a new reactive client on top of Vert.x, https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client, I think can be connected using the standard https://www.reactive-streams.org/

There is not a native reactive driver for DB2, one option is to create a Thread-pool to execute the database queries, Or you can use this [library](https://github.com/IBM/reactive-components) that already provides a Facade for that, but like this [post](https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/19/this-week-in-spring-december-18th-2018) mention is not really reactive.